# Powershell remove space around ForEach results

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to develop a PowerShell script that generates a output text file containing SQL statement.  I'm sure there are other ways to do this but I'm in a odd environment and this will get me what I need the fastest, I believe.  I'm trying to generate the SQL statements for use in MS Access.

I'm using PowerShell ISE to create and so far here is what I have:

```
$taskerIDs = Import-Csv C:\test.csv
ForEach ($row in $taskerIDs){write-host "SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites,"$row.ID"FROM Help_Data_List LEFT JOIN [TASKORD-"$row.ID"] ON Help_Data_List.[Sites] = [TASKORD-"$row.ID"].[Site Name] WHERE ((([TASKORD-"$row.ID"].[Site Name]) Is Null));"}
```

I'm doing this because I have around 50 rows in the CSV and I need the IDs listed there to be replaced in the write-host line.

The output to screen returns the following:

```
SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites, 12-0371 FROM Help_Data_List LEFT JOIN [TASKORD- 12-0371 ] ON Help_Data_List.[Sites] = [TASKORD- 12-0371 ].[Site Name] WHERE ((([TASKORD- 12-0371 ].[Site Name]) Is
 Null));
```

When you look at the result it shows [TASKORD- 12-0371 ] when it I'd like it to be [TASKORD-12-0371]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "construct" your output string like this:

```
"SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites,"$row.ID"FROM Help_D..."
```

The string literals and `$row.ID` entries are basically interpreted as individual strings, and `Write-Host` will add spaces between each of them.

Instead use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
"SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites,{0} FROM Help_D..." -f $row.ID
```

Put the expression in parentheses, so `Write-Host` gets the expanded string:

```
Write-Host ("SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites,{0} FROM Help_Data_List LEFT JOIN [TASKORD-{0}] ON Help_Data_List.[Sites] = [TASKORD-{0}].[Site Name] WHERE ((([TASKORD-{0}].[Site Name]) Is Null));" -f $row.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll review and update but this does appear to be what I need.  The above answer I marked since it got me what I needed immediately for the report I needed to get out :).

Comment: I would probably also use a format string, both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to access a property of a variable in a string, you need to use a *sub expression* `$()`for the string interpolation instead of using multiple double quotes:

```
# ....    
write-host "SELECT Help_Data_List.Sites,$($row.ID)FROM Help_Data_List LEFT JOIN [TASKORD-$($row.ID)] ON Help_Data_List.[Sites] = [TASKORD-$($row.ID)].[Site Name] WHERE ((([TASKORD-$($row.ID)].[Site Name]) Is Null));"
# ....
```